How to implement this zip function? zip[g,{f[{a,b}],f[{c,d}]}] to f[{g[{a,c}],g[{b,d}]}]
I have a function that returns an expression in the form f[{a,b}], and I use this function twice and assemble the expression {f[{a,b}],f[{c,d}]}. I wish to apply a function g to corresponding arguments and zip that up with the original head f.
To specify my use case, f is Row[] and {a,b} and {c,d} lists of  Plots. I want to Show corresponding plots together and zip that result up within Row again.
My question is Does this already exist? and if not How to nicely implement it?

I can't recall one single built-in function for the task, but here's a simpler solution for your specific task:
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}];
p2 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, Pi}];
p3 = Plot[Tan[x], {x, 0, Pi/2}];
p4 = Plot[Csc[x], {x, 0.1, Pi}];
p5 = Plot[Sec[x], {x, 0, Pi}];
p6 = Plot[Cot[x], {x, 0.1, Pi}];

r1 = Row[{p1, p2, p3}];
r2 = Row[{p4, p5, p6}];

Clear@show;
show[a__List] := MapThread[Show, {a}]

Thread[show[r1, r2], Row]

Based on the same idea, a generalized zip function can be defined as:
Clear@zip;
zip[g_, {expr : f_[__] ..}] :=
 Module[{func},
  func[a__List] := MapThread[g[{##}] &, {a}];
  Thread[func[expr], f]]

zip[g, {f[{a, b}], f[{c, d}]}]
(* f[{g[{a, c}], g[{b, d}]}] *)


I came up with this solution:
zip[fun_,exprs_List]:=First[Head/@exprs][Map[fun,Transpose[Flatten[List@@@exprs,1]]]]/;Length[Union[Head/@exprs]]==1

p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}];
p2 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, Pi}];
p3 = Plot[Tan[x], {x, 0, Pi/2}];
p4 = Plot[Csc[x], {x, 0.1, Pi}];
p5 = Plot[Sec[x], {x, 0, Pi}];
p6 = Plot[Cot[x], {x, 0.1, Pi}];

r1 = Row[{p1, p2, p3}];
r2 = Row[{p4, p5, p6}];


zip[Show, {r1, r2}]

Did I reinvent the wheel?
Revised answer
xzczd provided a nice answer that inspired me to read up on more sophisticated pattern matching (thank you for that!). My revised version of the zip function is
zip[f_, {exprs : h_[__] ..}] := f /@ Transpose[Identity@@@{exprs}] // h

I do not know if there are important differences between my version and theirs. Mine seems maybe a tad faster, but I didn't do thorough testing.

The following variant of your version is faster: zip[f_, expr : {h_[__] ..}] := h[f /@ Thread[Identity @@@ expr]]

Inspired by @E. Chan-López and @Tapiocaweasel's answers, another variant is:
zip[h_, expr : {f_[__] ..}] := f[h /@ Thread[{##}[[1]] & @@@ expr]]


A variant of the @Edmund's answer is as follows:
zip[h_, expr : {f_[__] ..}] := expr[[1, 0]][h /@ Thread[Splice@*List @@@ expr]]


zip[g, {f[{a, b}], f[{c, d}]}]


f[{g[{a, c}], g[{b, d}]}]


Your case is very specific and as such the affect can be achieved with MapApply and Part.
ClearAll[zip]
zip[h_, funcs_] := funcs[[1, 0]][h @@@ funcs]

Then
zip[g, {f[{a, b}], f[{c, d}]}]


f[{g[{a, b}], g[{c, d}]}]


Hope this helps.

So this is not quite right. I'm looking to zip the corresponding elements together, so {a,c} and {b,d} are paired.
